# How can I enable OpenGL on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: windows, gpu, opengl

I am trying to use an application requiring OpenGL > 2.1 on Windows Server.

I have read on multiple questions here about the challenges of getting OpenGL to work through a remote desktop session, but I am not there yet, and I am working directly on the server, with a monitor plugged into the GPU.

When I use the GPU on a desktop PC (Win 10), it correctly reads as using OpenGL 4.68, [as described in the GPU spec](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/design-visualization/productspage/quadro/quadro-desktop/proviz-print-nvidia-T400-datasheet-us-nvidia-1670004-r5-web.pdf).

However, if I take the same GPU, plug it into my test bench with Windows Server 2022, the same version of the drivers (Server OS branch), it caps at OpenGL 1.1

[image: GPU-Z screenshot]

Do you have any idea about what goes on?

Comment: Default Windows Server drivers (Windows HAL) doesn't support any kind of hardware acceleration. 

For full OpenGL support for NVIDIA T400 on Windows Server 2022 you should install NVIDIA Driver (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)

Comment: @Sergey I did install the latest version of the Nvidia driver for this graphics card